# No option to select home page in theme customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

My Website was working fine until yesterday and today when I tried to open it it was showing me the recent posts page not the page I set as home page. Tried to change the setting from Theme Customizer but there is no more the option to select the home page or post page. Is there a solution to this? Or should I just reinstall wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

To select your home page, go to `Settings` -> `Reading` and choose from the options 'Front Page Displays` provides.

In your case, the theme may or may not have an option to choose the front page from Customizer dependent on the developer.